# I need to create a multi dimentional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, cart

I need to create a multi dimentional array in php for a product cart.I need the cart to look something like this.

An array of orders which consist of array of products.

Main array should be like order 1 order 2 order 3 etc..
Inside each main array array of products with name,  product code.

```
Array ( [0] => Array 
  ( [0] => Array 
    ( [name] => Heart Choclates [code] => LFB-P-10 [qty] => 1 [type] => main [price] => 1200 [stock] => 5 [image] => choclates-valentines-day.jpg [quantity] => 12 [expdate] => May 25th 2017 [exptime] => 08:00 AM to 09:00 AM [expdtype] => Fixed time delivery
     ) 
  )
)
```

---

```
    //MySqli query - get details of item from db using product code
    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_code='$product_code' LIMIT 1");
    $obj     = $results->fetch_object();

    if ($results) { //we have the product info 

        //prepare array for the session variable
            if ($product_price == $obj->price) {
               $productextra= array(
                    $productslist = array(
                    'name' => $obj->product_name,
                    'code' => $product_code,
                    'qty' => $product_qty,
                    'type' => 'main',
                    'price' => $obj->price,
                    'stock' => $obj->stock,
                    'image' => $obj->image,
                    'quantity' => $obj->quantity,
                    'expdate' =>$_SESSION['dateofdelivery'],
                    'exptime' =>$_SESSION['timeslot'],
                    'expdtype'=>$_SESSION['typeofdelivery']
                    )
                );
            }
```

How can i modify this code to get it.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Birthday Pink [code] => KB-P-5 [qty] => 1 [type] => main [price] => 600 [stock] => 7 [image] => pink-roses.jpg [quantity] => 10 [expdate] => May 25th 2017 [exptime] => 12:00 PM to 04:00 PM [expdtype] => Standard delivery ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Signature Cake [code] => KB-P-7 [qty] => 1 [type] => addon [price] => 0 [stock] => 9 [image] => signature-cake.jpg [expdate] => May 25th 2017 [exptime] => 12:00 PM to 04:00 PM [expdtype] => Standard delivery ) [2] => Array ( [name] => Truffle Cake [code] => KB-P-8 [qty] => 1 [type] => addon [price] => 10 [stock] => 7 [image] => truffle-cake.jpg [expdate] => May 25th 2017 [exptime] => 12:00 PM to 04:00 PM [expdtype] => Standard delivery ) )
```

Comment: what's it producing currently?

Comment: Thank you for your response.Updated the question with current output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$productextra = array();
if ($product_price == $obj->price) 
{
   $productextra[] = array(
        $productslist => array(
        'name' => $obj->product_name,
        'code' => $product_code,
        'qty' => $product_qty,
        'type' => 'main',
        'price' => $obj->price,
        'stock' => $obj->stock,
        'image' => $obj->image,
        'quantity' => $obj->quantity,
        'expdate' =>$_SESSION['dateofdelivery'],
        'exptime' =>$_SESSION['timeslot'],
        'expdtype'=>$_SESSION['typeofdelivery']
        )
    );
}
```

The above code will output like

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [productslist_value] => Array ( [name] => name ) ) )
```

Or

```
$productextra = array();
if ($product_price == $obj->price) 
{
   $productextra[] = array(
        array(
        'name' => $obj->product_name,
        'code' => $product_code,
        'qty' => $product_qty,
        'type' => 'main',
        'price' => $obj->price,
        'stock' => $obj->stock,
        'image' => $obj->image,
        'quantity' => $obj->quantity,
        'expdate' =>$_SESSION['dateofdelivery'],
        'exptime' =>$_SESSION['timeslot'],
        'expdtype'=>$_SESSION['typeofdelivery']
        )
    );
}
```

It will output like

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => name ) ) )....
```

Comment: Hi, thanks it works but i need to know one more thing. how can i add an add on product inside the sub array like this Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => name ) Array ( [1] => Array ( [name] => name ) ) )....

Comment: Try this
`if ($product_price == $obj->price) 
{
    $products = array();
    array_push($products, array(
        'name' => $obj->product_name,
        'code' => $product_code,
        ....
        )
    ); 
    array_push($products,array(...)); // And so on.....
    $productextra[] = array($products);
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can run the below code [Here](http://phpfiddle.org/) and use which code you want

```
<?php
$productextra= array(
    $productslist = array(
        'name' => "Heart Choclates",
        'code' => "LFB-P-10",
        'qty' => 1,
        'type' => 'main',
        'price' => 1200,
        'stock' => "5",
        'image' => "choclates-valentines-day.jpg",
        'quantity' => "12",
        'expdate' => "May 25th 2017",
        'exptime' => "08:00 AM to 09:00 AM",
        'expdtype'=> "Fixed time delivery"
    )
);
$productslist = array(
    'name' => "Heart Choclates",
    'code' => "LFB-P-10",
    'qty' => 1,
    'type' => 'main',
    'price' => 1200,
    'stock' => "5",
    'image' => "choclates-valentines-day.jpg",
    'quantity' => "12",
    'expdate' => "May 25th 2017",
    'exptime' => "08:00 AM to 09:00 AM",
    'expdtype'=> "Fixed time delivery"
); 
$main_array=array(
    $productextra= array(
        $productslist = array(
            'name' => "Heart Choclates",
            'code' => "LFB-P-10",
            'qty' => 1,
            'type' => 'main',
            'price' => 1200,
            'stock' => "5",
            'image' => "choclates-valentines-day.jpg",
            'quantity' => "12",
            'expdate' => "May 25th 2017",
            'exptime' => "08:00 AM to 09:00 AM",
            'expdtype'=> "Fixed time delivery"
        )
    )
);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($productextra);
echo "<br>";
print_r($productslist);
echo "<br>";
print_r($main_array);
?>
```

OUTPUT

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Heart Choclates
        [code] => LFB-P-10
        [qty] => 1
        [type] => main
        [price] => 1200
        [stock] => 5
        [image] => choclates-valentines-day.jpg
        [quantity] => 12
        [expdate] => May 25th 2017
        [exptime] => 08:00 AM to 09:00 AM
        [expdtype] => Fixed time delivery
    )
)

Array
(
    [name] => Heart Choclates
    [code] => LFB-P-10
    [qty] => 1
    [type] => main
    [price] => 1200
    [stock] => 5
    [image] => choclates-valentines-day.jpg
    [quantity] => 12
    [expdate] => May 25th 2017
    [exptime] => 08:00 AM to 09:00 AM
    [expdtype] => Fixed time delivery
)

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Heart Choclates
                [code] => LFB-P-10
                [qty] => 1
                [type] => main
                [price] => 1200
                [stock] => 5
                [image] => choclates-valentines-day.jpg
                [quantity] => 12
                [expdate] => May 25th 2017
                [exptime] => 08:00 AM to 09:00 AM
                [expdtype] => Fixed time delivery
            )

    )
)
```